# Monomial ordering problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I've got the following problem:

> Let $\gamma$, $\delta$ $\in$ $\mathbb R_{> 0}$. The binary relation $\preceq$ on monomials in $X,Y$ is defined: $X^{m}Y^{n} \preceq X^{p}Y^{q}$ if and only if  $\gamma m + \delta n \leq \gamma p + \delta q .$ Show that this is a monomial ordering if and only if $ \frac \gamma \delta $ is irrational.

So since $\preceq$ is a partial order, do I just need to show that it is a total order only when $ \frac \gamma \delta $ is irrational?

Not really sure how to go about this, any guidance would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every monomial order is a total order; in particular when $\gamma/\delta$ is a rational $a/b$, we have $X^b\preceq Y^a\preceq X^b$, so $\preceq$ is not a total order, so $\preceq$ is not a monomial order.

But not every total order is a monomial order. To verify that $\preceq$ is a [monomial order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order) you have to show:

- it's a total order (easy)
- $u\preceq v$ implies $uw\preceq vw$ (hint: just expand the definition of $\preceq$)
- $\preceq$ is a well-ordering (hint: show that $\{(m,n)\in\mathbb N^2\mid \gamma m+\delta n\leq L\}$ is finite for any $L$)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't understand your first remark, why does $\frac \gamma \delta$ is a rational $\frac a b$ imply that $X^{a} \preceq Y^{b} \preceq X^{a} $?

Comment: By definition of $\preceq$, if $\gamma b=\delta a$ then $X^b\preceq Y^a$ and $Y^a\preceq X^b$ (note this isn't quite what you said in your comment).

Comment: Ahh right I see it now. Thanks alot for the help! much appreciated.